# C# Reading String inside a binary file

Tags: c#, hex

I have some problems to understand how reading files from different format than the text format. I know that inside a given file there are some information as string. I managed to write the hex code to a text file which is helping me a lot for another function of the process, because I know that after some combinations of hex codes there might be string writed in the file.

For instance, I have this batch of hex codes. 
00 39 AF 32 **DD 24 BA 09 07 06 03 DB**
I know that when the hex codes are equal to AF 32 the next information should be the string. For instance: "Invoice Number 223232"

Any help or reference will be appreciated.

Kind regards,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt", true);
      FileStream fs = new FileStream("File", FileMode.Open);
      int hexIn;
      String hex;
      for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++)
      {
         writer.Write(hexIn + " ");
         hex = string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
         writer.Write(hex + " ");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Show a sample of the data?

Comment: Try something like this :             string input = "00 39 AF 32 DD 24 BA 09 07 06 03 DB";
            byte[] output = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => byte.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();

Comment: Note, DD 24 BA 09 07 06 03 DB does not look a string in any common text encoding I have ever seen...

Comment: Is there an end byte value? If so I think this is a good candidate for regex.

Comment: There is a byte indicating the content lenght

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code you have looks like you are trying to read a binary file, not a hex-encoded text file.

If the source file is binary (which is ideal), you would read it byte-by-byte, and run through a state machine to know when to expect a string.  You would have to know how long the string is.  In the sample below I am assuming a null-terminated C-style string.  For pascal style strings you would read a length prefix, or for fixed width just keep track of the expected number of character.

```
bool done = false;
int state = 0;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while (!done) {
   int byteValue = fs.ReadByte();
   if (bytesValue == -1)
      done = true; 
   else {
      switch (state) {
         case 0: //looking for 0xAF
            if (byteValue == 0xAF) 
               state = 1;
            break;
        case 1: //looking for 0x32
            if (byteValue == 0x32)
                state = 2;
            else
                state = 0;
            break;
        case 2: //start reading string
            if (byteValue == 0) {//end of C-style string
                //Do something with result.ToString()
                result.Clear();
                state = 0;  //go back to looking for more strings
            } else {
                result.Append((char)byteValue); //assuming 8-bit ASCII string
            }
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

If you are reading a hex-encoded text file, it would be more difficult, as you would have to read hex nibbles at a time and reconstruct the bytes, but the state machine approach would be similar.

Comment: Hello, you are totally right, it's a binary file. I tried your code but byteValue is returning int numbers and not 0xAF or 0x32.

Comment: `(char)byteValue` also works with the assumption of ISO 8859-1. But why assume and why write it so esoterically? There is no text but encoded text. Just collect the byte sequence into `result` and convert it _with the encoding it was written with_ after the sequence is fully read.

Comment: I did some research about the file type I am trying to interpret: Advanced Function Presentation from IBM. 
Length A 2-byte field that specifies the length of the record (not including the 5A control character). Identifier (ID) A 3-byte field that specifies the type of the structured field. Flag byte A 1-byte field that specifies information about the data field. Sequence number A 2-byte field that identifies the record. Control and data A text control code, the name of an object, or coordinates for positioning an image or page segment. The control information is followed by the data.

Comment: @Faqundo That information should go in the question. Please [edit].

Comment: Indeed, the state machine will be much more complicated with the updated information-- and asking someone on stack overflow to write the whole thing would be inappropriate for the community.  I would suggest trying to code a state machine using my example to get started, and post a new question if you get stuck with that.